# Get all users that contributed to a wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to get back all users that contributed to a wordpress post. So the users that f.ex.: created and updated a post or custom fields in it.

I tried the following to get the users by a certain roles:

```
/* Query arguments. */
$query_args = array(
    'role' => $instance['role'],
    'number' => $limit
    );

$users = get_users( apply_filters( 'display_authors_widget_query', $query_args ) );
```

However, I am not sure how to get the users that "contributed" to a post. Are there a number of specific roles to query?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I don’t think WP does provide that by default. You might have to go through all the post revisions and check who the creating/editing “author” was.

Comment: @CBroe Thx, for your reply. You understood it totally right. I would appreciate if you could provide a coded answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these parameter with you arguments

```
$query_args = array(
        'role' => $instance['role'],
        'number' => $limit,
        'query_id' => 'authors_with_posts',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    );

 $users= new WP_User_Query( $query_args );
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! That gives me all authors of a certain posts. But I need all authors, editors, administrators etc. that created/updated the post.